# enqueuing wordpress scripts not fired

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a custom maintenance plugin for mywordpress projects. I have a problem with scripts, they will not be enqueued and I need to pass some parameter to my main javascript file to display a nice countdown timer. After some research I discovered that I'm using the `wp_loaded` hook that is fired too erly to permit that the scripts are loaded and I'm not able to use the `wp_loclaize_script` to pass the data to my js file. Is there another hook I can use?

```
  function maintenance_mode()
  {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php' && !current_user_can('manage_options') && !is_admin() ){
      header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable', true, 503 );
      header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
      if( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/maintenance.php' ) ) {
              require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/maintenance.php';
          }
      die();
    }
  }
  add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'maintenance_mode' );
```

Comment: Since this seems to be concerned with the `wordpress` ecosystem, if you don't get a response here, you should consider posting on this forum instead: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/